# SQLite equivalent of SQL Server DateAdd function

Tags: t-sql, sqlite

I need help reproducing the following SQL statement to a statement that SQLite understands.

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE [Date] >= DATEADD(day, -14, GETDATE())
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From this link

[Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

it would seem that you can use something like

```
date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...) 

SELECT date('now','+14 day');
```

Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: SQLite appears to lose the time portion of the column values, if there is any. SQL Server would have kept those for a DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME type. Just an observation.

Comment: SELECT date('2019-12-17 14:19:19','+14 day'); would lose the time part.

Comment: @MagnusSmith, datetime(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...) would be fine.

Answer (score 5):

The method Adriaan Stander gives result in GMT

You can do it in LocalTime like this

```
select DateTime('Now', 'LocalTime', '+1 Day');
```