# Date add for mysql and sqlite

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, laravel, phpunit

I have a application with MySQL query where I need add hours to the datetime. For this purpose is easy to use for example

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(some_column, INTERVAL 4 HOUR) FROM some_table
```

I'm using Laravel framework and only for testing I'm using SQLite where this date_add function does not exists and I have to use this query

```
SELECT datetime(some_column, "+4 Hour") FROM some_table
```

and this is the problem because application is using mysql while PHPUnit is using sqlite. Is there any workaround how to use function to add hours to the datetime which will works for both databases or is there any effective way how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has built in datetime in schembuilder
$table->timestamps();

More help https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns

Comment: I know that but I'm using PDO for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your date with PHP :

- date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+4 hours', strtotime($date)))

or

- date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+4 hours', $date)) if your date is a timestamp

Comment: I'm using function date_add as substring in From clause so I need to mysql to filter data and after then I will get the result so I cannot use PHP.

Comment: Have you check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32627612/5359470 ?

Comment: This is only transform from mysql to sqlite but I need function which will work for both databases, not for only one

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = Carbon:now()->addHours(4);
```

That will generate a timestamp that is 4 hours ahead of current time

Comment: Same as EkinsOf's answer, I cannot use PHP function instead MySQL function to get filtered data in subquery

Comment: edit your question to show us some sample record of the table and lets see the `DDL` of the table in question