# I want to fetch 30 days back results from sqlite DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to fetch 30 days back results from today in order to see who have not paid last month.

I tried something

```
SELECT * FROM MemberInformation WHERE DateOfAd = 'DATEADD(Day,-30,getdate())'
```

and query successfully executed but did not fetch the values I wanted.

My database:

[image]

please guys help me out...

Comment: What is the type of `DateOfAd` column?

Answer (score 1):

DATEADD is not work in sqlite you but you can use its sqlLite equivalent DateTime like code below :

```
select * from TableName where DateColumn < DateTime('Now', 'LocalTime', '-10 Day');
```

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

[SQLite equivalent of SQL Server DateAdd function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845563/sqlite-equivalent-of-sql-server-dateadd-function/1845633)

Comment: hi Amir sir, I tried but it fetch value of 2-10-2018 and 2-20-2018 . im sending screenshot sir kindly have a looks [link](https://ufile.io/1x7dr)

Comment: @user9587628 you can change '-10 Day' to '-30 Day'  and it returns data from 30 days ago

Comment: no sir i tried it ...if i change from -10 to -30 it not show any results. sir can you please connect by teamviewer if possible , or may i have your contact

Comment: @user9587628 what is your date look like ? give me some sample you are trying to fetch

Comment: it shows the result of 02-10-2018 and 02-20-2018 I attach screenshot sir on the above comment click on the link sir u can check it.

Comment: sir i tried something this `select Name from MemberInformation where DateOfAd = date ('now','-1 month')` to see name of on month back result . query get executed but value not fetch is there anything wrong

Comment: @user9587628 your date format i think is a wrong your date should looks like this yyyy/mm/dd

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM MemberInformation WHERE DateOfAd  BETWEEN datetime('now', '-30 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');
```

or Try to change where condition as,

```
WHERE DateOfAd  BETWEEN datetime('now', 'localtime', '-30 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');
```

Comment: thank your but it not fetch any value from database but query execute successfully

Comment: try #Jyoti Query and just remove `localtime` see this Query **`SELECT * FROM MemberInformation WHERE DateOfAd  BETWEEN datetime('now', '-30 days') AND datetime('now');`** @user9587628